# Какое окончание должно быть тут?

Tags: грамматика, окончания

"*Культура, как и общество, отдельно от природы*".
Нашел на одном сайте данное предложение. Разве не должны мы использовать "отдельна", ведь это слово относится к культуре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать как причастие, то необходимо другое слово:
*Культура, как и общество, **отделена** от природы.*

Согласование может быть связано с названием (титулкой) статьи:
*спорт отдельно от культуры*; || Представлен отдельно, рассматривается отдельно.
*культура отдельно от природы*.